# Closures in Ruby

Tags: ruby, closures

I'm having a little trouble with closures and I'd like to know what
the equivalent code for the canonical make-adder procedure would be in
Ruby.

In scheme it would be like:

```
(define (make-adder n)
 (lambda (x) (+ x n))
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's actually very close...

```
def make_addr n
  lambda { |x| x + n }
end
t = make_addr 100
t.call 1
101
```

In 1.9 you can use...

```
def make_addr n
  ->(x) { x + n }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

One difference is that while Scheme has only one kind of procedure, Ruby has four. Most of the time, they behave similarly enough to your standard lambda, but you should try to [understand all the details in depth](http://innig.net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do it in 1.9:

```
make_adder = -> n, x { n + x }
hundred_adder = make_adder.curry[100]
hundred_adder[4] # => 104
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty nice screen-cast explaining blocks and closures in Ruby:
http://www.teachmetocode.com/screencasts/8